# Google Charts backgroundColor not working with example code

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I use code from [example page](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart) to create horizontal bars chart:

Option backgroundColor work for other chart types, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/7wYP2/) and [that](http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/QjQNX/).

Is there are way to change background color for Bars charts?

```js
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages:['bar']});

function drawVisualization() {
    // Create and populate the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Opening Move', 'Percentage'],
          ["King's pawn (e4)", 44],
          ["Queen's pawn (d4)", 31],
          ["Knight to King 3 (Nf3)", 12],
          ["Queen's bishop pawn (c4)", 10],
          ['Other', 3]
        ]);
    
    var options = {
          backgroundColor: { fill: '#000' },//this is not working
          title: 'Chess opening moves',
          width: 900,
          legend: { position: 'none' },
          chart: { title: 'Chess opening moves',
                   subtitle: 'popularity by percentage' },
          bars: 'horizontal', // Required for Material Bar Charts.
          axes: {
            x: {
              0: { side: 'top', label: 'Percentage'} // Top x-axis.
            }
          },
          bar: { groupWidth: "90%" },
        };
    
    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('top_x_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

}

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

```html
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?fake=.js"></script>
<div id="top_x_div"></div>
```

chart

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using a Material Bar chart (See the [relevant documentation here](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#Material).)
See the comment at the end of the documentation paragraph :

> The Material Charts are in beta. The appearance and interactivity are
>   largely final, but the way options are declared is not. If you are
>   converting a Classic Bar Chart to a Material Bar Chart, you'll want to
>   replace this line:
>
> ```
> chart.draw(data, options);
> ```
>
> ...with this:
>
> ```
> chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
> ```

So if you want your standard options taken into account you need to wrap them with **google.charts.Bar.convertOptions()**.

Have a try, it works great. [See a jsfiddle of it here.](http://jsfiddle.net/rdtome/snor0ymq/)