# Can we change the background of google bar charts?

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I am working on google bar charts but I am not able to change the background color of google barcharts.
Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'category');
      data.addColumn('number', 'points');
      data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'style'});
      data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
      //data.addColumn({'type': 'string', 'role': 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}});
      data.addRows([
     ['Element', 'Density', { role: 'style' }],
     ['Copper', 8.94, '#b87333'],            // RGB value
     ['Silver', 10.49, 'silver'],            // English color name
     ['Gold', 19.30, 'gold'],
     ['Platinum', 21.45, 'color: #e5e4e2' ], // CSS-style declaration
  ]);
      var options = {
        title: 'Results',
         width: 700,
         height: 250,
        bar: {groupWidth: "40%"},
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Points',
          minValue: 0,
          maxValue:6,
          backgroundColor: 'none'
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'categories'
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('<?php echo $singleChartDivId; ?>'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  </script>
```

And result here is the link: http://prntscr.com/8nxsk7
But I want this type: http://prntscr.com/8nxts7

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart?hl=en

Comment: [Check here][1]

above link may suggest solution
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28177568/google-charts-backgroundcolor-not-working-with-example-code

Answer (score 0):

In options you can set backgroundColor:'color code' option.

Comment: background color basically change the whole color of the background. But I want different-2 color sepratelly

Comment: Are you want to change bar colors or whole chart background color??